# Возможность попробовать что-либо неоднократно

Tags: значение-слов

Можно ли попробовать что-то дважды, трижды? Корректно ли говорить "попробовал" в отношении, например, сигарет, если скурил намедни одну, но это случилось не впервой: также скурил одну лет десять назад, однако запамятовал вкус, ощущения? Может ли "пробовать" значить "использовать, употреблять" (пробовать хоть ежедневно борщ, пилу, зубную пасту)?

Comment: _**"неоднократно пробовал"**_. См. примеры: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6qZnHuOzjAhXIxIsKHbcLAdwQ_AUIFygB&biw=1250&bih=600

Comment: Вопрос по исправлениям. Почему "возможно" подходит меньше, чем "можно"? Потому что речь не об объективных истинах, а о языковых нормах?

Comment: Возможно, я и неправ, но мне кажется, что с глаголом хорошо сочетается только "можно": *можно ли сделать что-то/так-то.* Тем более и звучит проще. Если "можно" выражает то, что Вы хотели, зачем говорить сложнее? "Возможно" хорошо работает как вводное слово (у меня в начале комментария), в сочетаниях *возможна ли такая ситуация, возможно ли что-то,* то есть может ли что-то произойти. А когда Вы говорите "возможно ли попробовать", это невольно понимаешь как "есть ли **возможность** это попробовать", в то время как Вы имеете в виду просто "может ли такое быть, что пробуешь что-то дважды, трижды".

Answer (score 1):

Пробовать (в значении "пытаться", "испытывать" или "дегустировать") *можно* повторно или многократно в случаях, когда есть основания ожидать нового результата (внеся изменения в свои действия при новой попытке, изменения в конструкцию при новых испытаниях, добавив специй в блюдо).

> Макар Иванович *несколько раз пробовал* было приподняться, но ноги его
>   не слушались. (Ф. Достоевский, "Подросток")

Эйнштейн предостерегал против попыток получить новый результат, *пробуя* повторять одни и те же действия (*Безумие - делать одно и то же, и каждый раз ожидать иного результата*).

Comment: А зачем запятая в словах Эйнштейна?

Comment: Это отдельная тема (напр. "и" можно рассматривать со значением "при этом"): в одних изданиях она есть, в других - нет. Пример с запятой: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=u7ajBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT275&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0RPPLK33MRSgM60ipO8Ylb4n2zLw&w=1280